# Как сделать цену в корзине за 100 грамм? WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

У меня на странице товаров есть товары которые считаются за 100 грамм. И всё работает на странице магазина, но в корзине я получаю стоимость не за 100 грамм, а за 100 единиц товара. Вот код что бы понимали, что я имею.

Так вот, как мне сделать, что бы в корзине был расчёт за 100 грамм товара. То есть если покупатель возьмёт 300 грамм товара за 2$, то цена должна быть 6$. Сейчас она равно 600$.

В этом коде я просто задал шаг в 100 единиц.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 10, 2 ); // Simple products

function jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ) {
    $cat_arr = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(),'product_cat');
//это категория по которой я вывожу товары за единицу
    if( 'perunit' == $cat_arr[0]->name ) {
        if ( is_singular( 'product' ) ) {
            $args['input_value']    = 1;  // Starting value (we only want to affect product pages, not cart)
        }
        $args['max_value']  = 1000;     // Maximum value
        $args['min_value']  = 1;      // Minimum value
        $args['step']       = 1;    // Quantity steps
        return $args;
    }
// иначе, вывожу за 100 грамм
    else {
        if ( is_singular( 'product' ) ) {
            $args['input_value']    = 100;  // Starting value (we only want to affect product pages, not cart)
        }
        $args['max_value']  = 10000;     // Maximum value
        $args['min_value']  = 100;      // Minimum value
        $args['step']       = 100;    // Quantity steps
        return $args;
    }
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'jk_woocommerce_available_variation' ); // Variations

function jk_woocommerce_available_variation( $args ) {
    $args['max_qty'] = 1000;        // Maximum value (variations)
    $args['min_qty'] = 1;       // Minimum value (variations)
    return $args;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Все это можно сделать на хук `woocommerce_add_cart_item`. В `$cart_item_data['data']` храниться текущий продукт до момента добавления в корзину. С помощью метода `WC_Product::get_price` получаем текущую цену, а с помощью `WC_Product::set_price` изменяем ее:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item', 'my_add_cart_item_data' );
function my_add_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data ) {
    $product = $cart_item_data['data'];
    $product->set_price( $product->get_price() / 100 );

    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

Comment: Это не работает

Comment: почему? при добавлении товара обновляем цену

Comment: я не знаю, но ничего не работает

Comment: Как вы тестируете?